# Why is the distance greater with a margin top in IE?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, internet-explorer

I have the following component in my application

```css
.call-support {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.container-support {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.support-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.title-text {
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.subtitle-text {
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.customer-service-request {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10% 0 20% 0;
}



.request-text {
  display: flex;
}

.number {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #D53865;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f9f4f1;
  width: 340px;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.number:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 65px solid #666B74;
  border-left: 65px solid #f9f4f1;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 65px solid #666B74;
}

.subtitle-number {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.number-request {
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #666B74;
  height: 40px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 130px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="call-support">
  <div class="container-support">
    <div class="request-text">
      <p class="number">000 000 000<span class="subtitle-number">(local call)</span></p>
      <p class="number-request">Customer Service</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is well laid out with this css in all browsers, except in Internet Explorer where the margin top of "subtitle-number" shows it almost stuck to the margin-bottom of the box it belongs to.

Here I leave a link to a codepen with the design.

https://codepen.io/CharlieJS/pen/dyXyBBe

and an image of how it looks in Internet Explorer[image]

How can I adjust the design to display in all browsers?

Why is the margin-bottom higher in IE?

thank you all for your time and help

Comment: 1st please accept edit, to set snippet and correct `font-size:16;` to `font-size: 18px;` applied on: `.number-request`

Comment: @MaxiGui please don’t _falsify_ the code people are posting with your edits. If you think changing the mentioned font size to what you said is (part of) the solution, then you should either suggest that in a comment, or write an answer.

Comment: @04FS I don't think that it is part of the solution, I think that he did not pay attention by making example. As his image is fine and it is not the problem he describes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is created by `display: flex;` in class `.subtitle-number`. So just remove it and it will work fine.

Try to set this class wit top & left like:

```
.subtitle-number {
      position: absolute;
      font-family: "RalewayRegular";
      font-weight: normal;
      font-size: 12px;
      /*display: flex;
      margin-top: 40px;*/
      top:70%;
      left:50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 30%);
    }
```

As position absolute is better set with `top, right, bottom, left`. It seems to work fine by me on w3schools on IE11.

### DEMO

```css
.call-support {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}

.container-support {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.support-text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.title-text {
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.subtitle-text {
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.customer-service-request {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10% 0 20% 0;
}



.request-text {
  display: flex;
}

.number {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #D53865;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f9f4f1;
  width: 340px;
  height: 130px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.number:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 65px solid #666B74;
  border-left: 65px solid #f9f4f1;
  width: 0;
  border-bottom: 65px solid #666B74;
}

.subtitle-number {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  /*display: flex;
  margin-top: 40px;*/
  top:70%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 30%);
}

.number-request {
  font-family: "RalewayRegular";
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #666B74;
  height: 40px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 130px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="call-support">
  <div class="container-support">
    <div class="request-text">
      <p class="number">000 000 000<span class="subtitle-number">(local call)</span></p>
      <p class="number-request">Customer Service</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, in the rest of the browsers it works without any problem but in Internet Explorer it is still the same but it is shown at the end of its div

Comment: @javascript110899 ok try with `top:70%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 30%);` and remove your margin-top. (I edited my answer)

Comment: thank you! sorry for the delay. with the update it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

The absolute property is set in this style but the coordinate value is not set. Because of the different calculation methods such as element position parameters in different    browsers, the results are not the same in different browsers.

At this time, it is not necessary to use relative positioning, but to have a certain coordinate. Please modify the `.subtitle-number` style as following:

```
.subtitle-number {
     position: absolute;
     font-family: "RalewayRegular";
     font-weight: normal;
     font-size: 12px;
     top: 80px;
     left: 145px;
 }
```

Result in IE:
[image]